# How to host mySQL server on other system on LAN?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Okay, so I have an mySQL server running on NUE-1-5 (192.168.1.125). I have phpMyAdmin being hosted on this system too so I can easily manage the sql remotely. I have another server called NUE-1-6 (192.168.1.126) hosting an altis life server for arma 3. when i host the mySQL server for altis life on NUE-1-6 it works fine. but i want to put it on NUE-1-5 so I can manage all the databases with phpMyAdmin. but when I set the extDB (the datatbase manager for arma 3) config file to run the database off NUE-1-5 i get this error:

> extDB: Database Exception Error: Connection attempt failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'NUE-1-5' (using password: YES)

Ive checked another stack overflow pages on similar errors, but i've tried all the comments, and nothing worked. its not just extDB, when i try to login with any programs that use mySQL i cant connect unless its on the same machine.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

This MySQL query should give access to all your 192.168.xxx.xxx subnet:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* To 'your-db-user'@'192.168.1.125/255.255.0.0'
```

This should give access to all your 192.168.1.xxx subnet:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* To 'your-db-user'@'192.168.1.125/255.255.255.0'
```